# To hat, or not to hat, that is the question

Tags: discussion, hats

> To hat, or not to hat, that is the question:
>
> Whether 'tis Nobler in the mind to carry
>
> The Badges and Perks of outrageous Actions,
>
> Or to take Arms against a Sea of hat-tings,
>
> And by opposing end them: to null, to voids
>
> No more; and by a null, to say we end
>
> The Head-ache, and the thousand Natural hats
>
> Avatars are heir to? 'Tis a consummation
>
> Devoutly to be wished. To voids, to null,
>
> To null, perchance to seg fault; aye, there's the rub,
>
> For in that sleep of [NULL], what dreams may come,
>
> When we have shuffled off this mortal coil,
>
> Must give us pause.

Ok I'm not a poet. [This is actual monologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_be,_or_not_to_be). :)

Seriously though, Stack Exchange is doing [Winterbash](http://stackexchange.com/promos/15/winter-bash-2014) and wondering if we want to have hats or not!

Winterbash gives people the opportunity to gain hats (kind of like badges) but then those go onto avatars from December 14, 2015 through January 3rd, 2016. You can see a [countdown](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) if you are interested.

Just a logistical note, only upvotes will 'count' for voting.

So to hat, or not to hat, that is the question!

Comment: Just a note, **only upvotes** are going to be used to count for voting (feel free to downvote away on whichever you disagree with, though!).

Comment: Are there any reasons not to hat? Seems like harmless fun to me!

Comment: 0/10, not in iambic pentameter =P

Comment: ___Hat___ is the question!

Comment: And hatters gonna hat.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Yes**! Workplace **should** participate in Winterbash 2015.

Comment: I can't vote for my own answer... silly SE preventing me from sock puppeting. But my avatar is so great for hats!

Comment: My avatar is NOT so great for hats :O  But I still think we should participate :)

Answer (score 15):

**Yes!** Workplace **should** participate in Winter Bash 2015.

However, [enderland](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2322/enderland) should be barred from participation.

Answer (score -7):

**No**! Workplace **should NOT** participate in Winterbash 2015.

Comment: Hats suck and are only for people who like having fun.... and everyone knows we hate fun here at SE!

Comment: @Chad I find your lack of hat disturbing... :o