# Winterbash 2016?

Tags: discussion

I'm [not going to try poetry again for this year's winterbash post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3423/2322)...

Winterbash is a competition within SE that allows everyone to win hats by doing various things, similar to badges, but only from December 19th through January 8th, 2017. Any hats can then be displayed on your avatar during this time like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vvIl.png]

The full summary from last year is [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/Winter-Bash-2015-Hats-Off/).

Some hats will have public descriptions to aim for but some have secret criteria (though there normally ends up being a long thread on meta.stackexchange with a list if you really want to find them that way).

Winterbash is opt-out, so unless there are significant objections, Workplace will be opted in.

Winterbash, yay or nay?

Comment: Not quite yay, but yea anyway.

Comment: Just had a big laugh about my hat, it's so silly har har, big YAY!

Answer (score 34):

Definitely a YAY!

Apparently there was only one site that usually opts out - lets not be that site.

(plus - I like hats!)

Comment: Yay! It's *hat* time of the year again :)

Comment: Wait, there's a site that doesn't like hats? They like fun even less than we do!

Comment: Which site doesn't like hats?

Comment: @WorkerWithoutACause Math Overflow